# Calling an XPage through ajax call

Tags: ajax, xpages, lotus-domino

**Scenario**

Lotus Domino form with a button that made an Ajax call to an Xpage, that do some stuff (read a properties file).

Framework: *prototype.js*

**Button code:**

```
var now = new Date()
var n = $H({
            ........
    now: now.getTime()      
});

var url = "/" + $F("path") + "/myxpages.xsp";
var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
    url, 
{
    method: 'post', 
    parameters: n.toQueryString(), 
    onComplete: function(response) {

                      ajaxResult = response.responseText;
            }
});
```

**Xpage**

*myxpages.xsp* has this SSJS code on *afterPageLoad* event

```
 var request = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
 var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
 response.setHeader("Expires", -1);
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

 com.org.MyGetProperties.readProperties(request,response);
```

**MyGetProperties class**

This class is deployed in *WebContent/WEB-INF/classes*

```
public class MyGetProperties {

    static PrintWriter out = null;

    public static synchronized void readProperties(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        try {
                *(DO SOME STUFF HERE)*
                out = new PrintWriter(response.getWriter());

                // return result
                out.println("OK");

            } catch (Exception e) {..}
    }
}
```

Sometimes *ajaxResult* variable in ajax response call is *empty*, sometimes is *"OK"*, as expected (seems to be something related to cache, but i think i've managed it correctly).

The behavior is different on different production server, i don't know if depends on server configurations.

Could be a PrintWriter problem?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: don't. Long answer: use the Ajax control. You put that on your page and your URL changes to myxpages.xsp/nameyougavetheajaxcontrolproperty

This way you can be sure not to run foul of any cached result or pending operation. It also has a property where you can specify a Java class directly. That class extends (need to Google that - answered it on SO before) which gives you direct access to request/response

**Update:**

You need to tell that you are done:

```
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

See my [original post on XAgents](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/shwl-7mgfbn), the [revision](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8BYMW8) and some [thought on testing](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SLCVR).

Comment: Is it possible to use it also on 8.5.3?

Comment: Yes. Either use 8.5.3 updatepack 1 or the Extlib from OpenNTF

Comment: Without follow this way (install Extlib on thousand production server could be a very hard work), what could be a reason of this beheaviour?

Comment: Deploying Extlib is actually *very* easy: put it into an update site, replicate that site to all servers (that is drag & drop in the admin client). Add the ini value to the configuration document (can be done using a small script). You can be done before lunch. - My answer updated